# How do I get a list of domain names from a list of emails in Bash?

Tags: bash

I wrote a program that takes a list of emails from a directory and all of its sub-directories and counts every email that occurs.

What I want to do now is take from THAT list and show a list of domains that appear the most.

```
shopt -s globstar

PUNISHED=$1
VENOM=$2

echo >> topemails.txt
echo >> emails_top_domains.txt

for files in ./$(VENOM)/**/*; do
    if [ -f "${files}" ] ; then

          < "$files" tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]' \
            | grep -Eiorh '([[:alnum:]_.-]+@[[:alnum:]_.-]+?\.[[:alpha:].]{2,4})' 2> /dev/null \
            | sort -nr \
            | uniq -c > topemails.txt
    fi

done

         < topemails.txt \
        | grep -Eiorh '(@[[:alnum:].-]+?\.[[:alpha:].]{2,4})' 2> /dev/null \
        | tr -d "@"  \
        | uniq -u > emails_top_domains.txt

echo "The top \"${PUNISHED}\" emails are"
head -$PUNISHED topemails.txt

echo "The top domains are"
head -$PUNISHED emails_top_domains.txt
```

A problem I keep running into is that I get domains that repeat themselves in my list, which should not happen if I use uniq -u, right?

My code works like this, I call the script, with N variables and a directory.

./myscript 10 /home/alabasterTenRing/

It would print the list of emails that appear the most in the files from that domain and its subdirectories, and then it should print a list of domains that appear the most as well as putting those domain names to a file.

However, here is the list of domain names that appear:

```
mail.goo.ne.jp
gmail.com
jlt3.sipsolutions.net
freewrt.org
yahoo.com
in.ibm.com
gmail.com
arm.com
arndb.de
gmail.com
```

gmail should not repeat twice let alone three times. Clearly I did something wrong here, where did I go wrong?

Comment: replace `uniq -u` with `sort -u`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't sort your input before passing to `uniq -u`. From man `uniq` does:

> Filter adjacent matching lines..

If the matching lines are not adjacent, uniq will print them again.

For your case, you could just use `sort -u`. But the `sort | uniq -u` will also work.

Notes:

- you are recreating the file `topemails.txt` in each loop, because you use `>`. Most probably you want to append to the file.
- the `for files.. if -f` looks like it can be just replaced with `find ./$(VENOM) -type f` and a `while read` or maybe with just `find ./(VENOM) -type f | xargs cat | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' ....`
- The `[` `]` in front and after class in `tr` are not needed. Because they are specified in both input and replacement, tr replaces `[` for `[` and `]` for `]`, they are interpreted as normal characters, not specially handled.

Comment: Got it, by the way to append should I replace > with >> ?